# Admin SDK -- get information about the group

Tags: php, web, oauth, google-admin-sdk

Please, help. https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/106274944935548788283 sending a GET request to obtain information about the group with id 1062 ... Here is a link to the method in Google https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_group In response get the error - 401 Unauthorized. With OAuth to authenticate via a user has received all the rights that are necessary for the request, included in the console Admin SDK. Authorization is successful, there is a token. What is not so I can not understand. If not hard - response.

Requested information:

```
file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/1062749‌​44935548788283?key=AIzaSyBrUhIOMDf9NlX9Lx3ImXWEsQMcRNhH4L4");
```

---

```
id group - "106274944935548788283" 


Key applications just in case - "AIzaSyBrUhIOMDf9NlX9Lx3ImXWEsQMcRNhH4L4"  

Error: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: Just how are we supposed to help you when you provide us with so littel to work with? Add the relevant code from your app

Comment: Request for information:
`file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/106274944935548788283?key=AIzaSyBrUhIOMDf9NlX9Lx3ImXWEsQMcRNhH4L4");`
------------------------------
"106274944935548788283" - id group
"AIzaSyBrUhIOMDf9NlX9Lx3ImXWEsQMcRNhH4L4" - Key applications just in case.  
Error: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized

Comment: In future edit the question, the information is more readable that way. I have edited your question for you this time

Comment: While making request to groups as a user, Is the user impersonated https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount  to access Admin sdk? Also, are you able to try your request in the API explorer here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/get

Comment: For authentication, the service account is not used, I use a normal user Google+ What to use? We need to get the user community, about the community.

Comment: You can use Google+ sign in too for admin sdk. Please check your authorization headers. It could be problem with the header.